# How to disable loading React Devtools Backend script

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

On production react_devtools_backend.js is loading anyway and it slows up my website in production. How to disable loading this react devtools?
I'm using react 16.8, reactSSR, webpack 4.29, apollo

I've alreadyused

```js
 new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      '__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__': '({ isDisabled: true })'
    }),
```

and

```js
if (typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === "object") {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__)) {
        window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__[key] = typeof value == "function" ? ()=>{} : null;
    }
}
```

and

```js
<script>
        if (typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === 'object') {
            __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function() {};
        }
</script>
```

and this

```js
const disableReactDevTools = (): void => {
    const noop = (): void => undefined;
    const DEV_TOOLS = (window as any).__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__;

    if (typeof DEV_TOOLS === 'object') {
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(DEV_TOOLS)) {
            DEV_TOOLS[key] = typeof value === 'function' ? noop : null;
        }
    }
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

Comment: In all versions it's not working. And even in production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but it seems to be loaded as a result of having installed the extension.

When I fired up an incognito window, it wasn't getting loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Its loaded from chrome extension: React Developer Tools
You can go to Network tab, find redundant script(click on it). Then you can go to 'Initiator' tab - there you will see where it came from.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is true, it is downloaded by 'React Developer Tools' extension. Try to turn off the extension and then refresh the page. You will se that no request was sent.